# VBA Excel to Hide faster more than 300,000 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have row more than 300.000 rows in excel
then i wanna do this job

1. Compare coulmn  C & D and results shown in E
2. Hide all Rows with TRUE Value and only show the FALSE

[image]

i've trying to use this code, but its takes more than 15 mins to hide the rows

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i, Hide, popup  As Long 
LastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
  If Range("C" & i).Value = Range("D" & i).Value Then
      Range("E" & i).Value = "True"
  Else
  Range("E" & i).Value = "False"


  End If
 If Cells(x, "E").Value = "True" Then
 Rows(x).Hidden = True

End If

Next
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Next i
```

Comment: In your code you don't show `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and
`Application.ScreenUpdating = False` lines. Do you have these?

Comment: yes i have that code but not impact to this code

Comment: Note that if you declare `Dim i, Hide, popup As Long` only `popup` is of type `Long` but the other 2 are `Variant`. In VBA you must declare a type for **every** variable otherwise they are `Variant` by default: `Dim i As Long, Hide As Long, popup As Long`

Comment: Try using a database (e.g sql server) to peform db tasks (xompare mfilter) and just link a query to sheet.(data connection)

Comment: @ComputerVersteher i know , but i just wanna share this data using Excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With sht.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=C2=D2"
    .Value = .Value
    .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
End With
```

That should be faster.  Don't turn off calculation before doing that though!

Comment: instead of .Formula and .Value you could avoid evaluating on sheet by: .Value = Application.Evaluate("C2:C" & LastRow & "=D2:D" & LastRow)

Comment: @EvR - I did consider that (but using sht.Evaluate to make sure the formula is evaluated for the correct sheet) and it might have been a safer bet not knowing how calculation is set.

Comment: Friendly hint: take into account that `.AutoFilter` (as well as Conditional Formatting) always uses regional settings, so one has to use e.g. `Criteria1=FALSCH` in German instead of `FALSE`, respectively `WAHR` instead of `TRUE` :-)